# Force browser to use HTTP because of HTTP proxy

Tags: proxy, ssl, https

I have a lot of HTTP proxies and I cannot access websites that are using SSL through those proxies. I have no access to configuring the proxies, so is it possible to force Firefox (in my case) to connect to the website with HTTP instead of HTTPS?

Comment: If you manually use "HTTP" and try to access the HTTPS site(s), does it work, and do they remain as HTTP?

Comment: Nope, I am trying to access the site with http:// which does not work.

Comment: Is this because hte proxy doesn't allow HTTP (the protocol), or is it that it ONLY allows requests to port 80 through? If the site doesn't answer to HTTP (or forces a redirect to HTTPS, or to another port/protocol that the proxy doesn't support), then there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: I am not sure, it's a public proxy so I don't really have much information about it, other than its only HTTP.

Comment: Then I believe you're SOL my friend. HTTP-only proxies only support proxying HTTP.

Comment: Okay, do you have any idea why Captchas on websites are not showing up when I am connecting through a proxy? In this case I connected to a HTTPS site through a HTTPS proxy. It's not like the proxy removes images, because I can see plenty of images that belongs to the website.

Comment: Calls to an HTTPS address (say a 3rd party service that delivers Captcha images) in the page your are using HTTP to view.  Your browser tries to follow the HTTPS connection referenced on the page/in JavaScript, and that call fails due to your proxy not supporting HTTPS, so you get no image.